# How to copy an artefact from one agent to another in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'd like to use a Jenkins declarative pipeline and the agent syntax to build an artefact that I want to then deploy to a side car container, as illustrated in this pseudo-code:

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Build Artefact') {
            agent { docker 'build-agent' } 
            steps {
                < I want to create the artefact to deploy to a side car container here >
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Artefact') {
            agent { docker 'side-car' } 
            steps {
                < I want to deploy the artefact created in the previous stage here >
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am struggling with is working out how to pass a file from the container used by the 'Build Artefact' stage to the container used in the 'Deploy Artefact', as far as I am aware `stash` will not work across containers, unless anyone has experience otherwise.

According to the Jenkins documentation, you can use the args argument to specify a volumes for the declarative pipeline syntax:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution that does not involve passing volumes around.

Comment: Use bind mount volumes. Then you can build a file to your host machine, and then have the next container use that same mount to access that file.

Comment: That occurred to me as the way to go were I to use jenkins script and spin up containers via bat or sh calls to docker, however, I am not sure how this would work or if you can even do this using the declarative pipeline agent syntax.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? I regularly use the pipeline syntax to build, start, and run containers. So long as it's running on the same slave, you'd be good.

Comment: There are two pipeline syntax's, scripted and declarative, which one are you using ?

Comment: According to the Jenkins documentation you can specify volumes for docker based agents:

pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B'
            }
        }
    }
}

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this, however this provides a solution.

Comment: I should mention that I'm shelling out for all my Docker commands

Comment: That is what I have done mostly, I'm looking at using the declarative syntax though because, and this might just be my own personal take, I think its more elegant.

Comment: Why does `stash` not work?

Answer (score 11):

Provided that the artifact isn't too big, you can use the `stash` directive to pass some file(s) between stages in different containers.

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Build Artefact') {
            agent { docker 'build-agent' } 
            steps {
                sh 'make'
                stash includes: 'myartefact', name: 'ARTEFACT'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Artefact') {
            agent { docker 'side-car' } 
            steps {
                unstash 'ARTEFACT'
                sh 'deploy.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For full details see the [stash Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)

Comment: This was a lifesaver! I think you might want your stash `includes` to be `myartefact/**/*` at least in current Jenkins pipeline so it grabs all the files though. It uses ANT matching syntax.

Comment: I think it depends what your output actually is.  Typically the pattern is for the package stage to produce a singular bundle for deployment (be that a zip, tarball, jar, war, go binary, etc.), but there certainly may be cases where a glob pattern is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can map a logical docker volume with your physical jenkins directory (the own job workspace for example) using the -v parameter when you use the "docker run".

Here is more detailed:

https://damnhandy.com/2016/03/06/creating-containerized-build-environments-with-the-jenkins-pipeline-plugin-and-docker-well-almost/